# How to use Raspbian "Wheezy" with a single mouse button

Tags: mouse, raspberry-pi

I am controlling my Raspberry Pi with some old Apple stuff. Thus, my mouse only has a single mouse button. Is there any way for me to use right-click functionality within the Raspbian OS, or do I need to buy a new mouse?

Comment: Does F12 still work as right-click under wheezy?

Comment: @Paul thanks for the suggestion, but it wasn't helpful. Maybe it is because I am using an Apple keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mouseemu` to emulate the buttons on your keyboard - the configration files are at `/etc/default/mouseemu`. [Ode2 has a useful set of sample configurations](http://www.ode2.com/?p=83) for a sane setup - suggesting that you merely un-comment the lines for rightclick and middle click. As always, read the manpage for more ideas on how to use the software.